# How to create spaces between characters in power point using pptx python?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

[image]I have a string and I want to use character spacing in this string, it is 'normal' but I want to choose 'loose' option. How can I do it using pptx python? I know I can put spaces manually between each character to look like spaced but I want to use this character spacing. So can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can adjust the spacing in the VBA IDE by typing this into the Immediate window after selecting a text box:

```
activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 25
```

25's a wee bit extreme, but the results are quite visible.

Or more generally, changing a shape's TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing property will change the letter spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set any character spacing for text in PowerPoint presentations using [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/) as shown below:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

file_name = "example.pptx"
slide_index = 0
shape_index = 0
paragraph_index = 0
portion_index = 0

with slides.Presentation(file_name) as presentation:

    # Get a shape with a text.
    shape = presentation.slides[slide_index].shapes[shape_index]

    # Get a text portion to change the spacing.
    text_portion = shape.text_frame.paragraphs[paragraph_index].portions[portion_index]

    # Set the character spacing to 10, for example. 
    text_portion.portion_format.spacing = 10
```

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/python/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to do the same using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```py
import asposeslidescloud

from asposeslidescloud.apis.slides_api import SlidesApi

slides_api = SlidesApi(None, "my_client_id", "my_client_key")

file_name = "example.pptx"

# 1-based indices
slide_index = 1
shape_index = 1
paragraph_index = 1
portion_index = 1

# Get a text portion to change the spacing.
text_portion = slides_api.get_portion(
    file_name, slide_index, shape_index, paragraph_index, portion_index)

# Set the character spacing to 10, for example. 
text_portion.spacing = 10

# Update the text portion.
slides_api.update_portion(
    file_name, slide_index, shape_index, paragraph_index, portion_index, text_portion)
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try this sometime. Really appreciate your answer. Cheers!!